# Repetir reproduccion de banner animado

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Hice una banner animado en [Google Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/) y ya la puedo visualizar en el navegador, pero solo se muestra o reproduce una vez.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se reproduzca infinitamente?

Comment: ¿En Advanced Mode?

Comment: Advanced Mode que es?

Comment: Por lo que hallé en un grupo puedes ciclarlo infinitamente seleccionando el botón en la parte superior de la línea de tiempo que sale en el modo avanzado `Advanced Mode`. Info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwdbeta/QMdNmEBHf2g

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro al hacer eso se repite pero en el programa, mas no en el navegador

Comment: Podrías entrar en la pestaña del código (_Code view_) y cambiar el valor de las repeticiones en la animación de 1 a `infinite`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en que parte del código hago ese cambio?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tu comentario soluciono el problema, por favor responde la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Perdón, estaba en el trabajo y no pude responder. Me alegra que el comentario te sirviera de todos modos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes entrar en la pestaña del código (vista de codigo) y en el css cambiar el valor de las repeticiones en las animaciones de 1 a infinite, por ejemplo :

Asi viene el codigo css por defecto de las animaciones

```
#page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-66zmgwdanimation {
  animation: gwd-gen-66zmgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 1s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

entonces quedaría así:

```
#page1.gwd-play-animation .gwd-gen-66zmgwdanimation {
  animation: gwd-gen-66zmgwdanimation_gwd-keyframes 1s linear 0s infinite normal forwards;
}
```

Esto solucionaría tu pregunta.